# Android: Camera taken but the image was mirrored

Tags: android, image, camera, photo, flip

I have problem with image taken by the front camera. I can display the front camera properly but the image captured was mirrored. Rotation won't work here
so what can I do to flip it correctly

Comment: how do you take the photo use intent to open camera app or using your own view?

Comment: i use my own surfaceview to show the preview in portrait front camera

Comment: Ok I found the solution.. using matrix.prescale(1.0,-1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution.. using matrix.prescale(1.0,-1.0)